# Conforming to NodeInitializable using try node.extract with transform parameter

Tags: swift, swift3, vapor

I am getting started with Vapor and I am trying to create a model for a `class` called `Intubation`. When you are conforming to the `NodeInitializable` you have to have this function:

```
init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    intubationID = try node.extract("intubationID")
    attempt = try node.extract("attempt")
}
```

I am getting an error regarding the line `attempt = try node.extract("attempt")` saying

**Missing argument for parameter 'transform' in call**

If `attempt` is an instance of `class Attempt` how do I go about conforming to `NodeInitializable` in a correct way

Comment: If I am correct, you can't extract a custom class from a `Node` like that. You would either have to store the lower level types, such as `Int`, `String`, `Bool`, etc., to initialize the instance of the class or create a `Pivot` to store the properties of an `Attempt` in the database and have a [sibling relationship](https://videos.raywenderlich.com/screencasts/server-side-swift-with-vapor-sibling-relations).

Answer (score 0):

The class `Attempt` must also be `NodeInitializable` for the `node.extract` call to work.

```
extension Attempt: NodeInitializable { ... }
```

That should fix it